# Attach image is misssing sharing to facebook

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am making an android app and for this app I need to share an image to facebook. I already follow all the procedure from facebook sharing website. But While clicking the share button it shows the image but while sharing the image is missing. My detailed code is-

```
   public class ActivityShare extends Activity {




String[] ShareOption; //create a shareOption array
Spinner ShareOptionList; // define A spinner list to choose the score type
int driverStarScore = 4; // define a drivingstar score to give the star to a driver .
Facebook fb; // define facebook
SharedPreferences sp;
ImageView pic;

ListView list; // define list

 String[] ShareItemName ={  //create a string array of shareItem name

 "Dropbox",
 "Email",
 "Facebook",
 "Google Plus",
 "Twitter",
 "Whatsapp",

 };

 Integer[] ShareImageId={  //create an integer array of images of the shareitem

         R.drawable.ic_dropbox,
         R.drawable.ic_email,
         R.drawable.ic_facebook,
         R.drawable.ic_googleplus,
         R.drawable.ic_twitter,
         R.drawable.ic_whatsapp,

         };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_share);

    sp=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String access_token= sp.getString("access_token", null);
    long expires=sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);

    if(access_token!=null){
        fb.setAccessToken(access_token);

    }
    if(expires !=0){
        fb.setAccessExpires(expires);
    }

    String APP_ID=getString(R.string.APP_ID);
    fb=new Facebook(APP_ID);



    ShareOptionList=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_ShareScore);
    ShareOption=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ShareChooseOption);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,ShareOption);
    ShareOptionList.setAdapter(adapter1);

    ShareOptionList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int index=arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You select "+ ShareOption[index],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    });




    ShareListAdapter adapter=new ShareListAdapter(this, ShareItemName, ShareImageId);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview_share);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String Selecteditem= ShareItemName[+position];  //response to click on the list

         Toast.makeText(ActivityShare.this, Selecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         if(Selecteditem=="Facebook"){  //if facebook item is pressed





                    Bundle params=new Bundle();
                     params.putString("name", "ASSES ME");
                     params.putString("caption", "My Driving Score");
                     params.putString("link", "http://www.mybringback.com/"); //the link of the app

                     if (driverStarScore == 1){   // if someone got 1 star
                    params.putString("picture", "http://media-cerulean.cursecdn.com/attachments/8/944/1star.png"); //image copied from a Website
                     params.putString("description", "My score is Sufficient"); //summary of a driver
                     }
                     else if (driverStarScore == 2){  // if someone got 2 star
                     params.putString("picture", "http://media-cerulean.cursecdn.com/attachments/8/946/2star.png");//image copied from a Website
                     params.putString("description", "My score is Satisfactory");//summary of a driver
                     }
                     else if (driverStarScore == 3){  // if someone got 3 star
                    params.putString("picture", "http://media-cerulean.cursecdn.com/attachments/8/948/3star.png");

                    params.putString("description", "My score is Good");
                     }
                     else if (driverStarScore == 4){
                    params.putString("picture", "http://media-cerulean.cursecdn.com/attachments/8/950/4star.png");
                    params.putString("description", "My score is Really Good");

                     }

                     else if (driverStarScore == 5){
                    params.putString("picture", "http://media-cerulean.cursecdn.com/attachments/8/951/5star.png");
                     params.putString("description", "My score is Best");
                     }


                        fb.dialog(ActivityShare.this,"feed",params, new DialogListener(){


                    @Override
                         public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e){
                            //TODO Auto-generated method stub 
                         }
                         @Override
                         public void onError(DialogError e){
                             //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onCancel(){
                             //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         }
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Editor editor=sp.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",fb.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires", fb.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }
                });











             }
```

Comment: I need a solution for this.

Comment: From the code, it doesn't look like the official Facebook Android SDK - which SDK are you using? Have you tried using the code snippets provided for the official SDK from Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android)?

Comment: Thank you @subeeshb. I fixed my problem. Now I can Share the image to facebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using facebook sdk version 4
 than use this code for sharing Image with Text. This is works for me.

1.declaire variable

```html
private LoginManager manager;
```

2.put this in onCreate and change your layout name

```html
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
setContentView(R.layout.Your_layout);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
```

3.call this method for sharing

```html
public void FaceBookSharing() {
 List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
 manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);
 manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
 new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
 shareImage();
 }
 @Override
 public void onCancel() {
 System.out.println("onCancel");
 }
 @Override
 public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
 System.out.println("onError");
 }
});
}

private void shareImage() {
//use your image bitmap here
 Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
    R.drawable.ic_launcher);
 SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image)
    .setCaption("Hey this is only demo text.!")
    .build();
 SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder().addPhoto(
    photo).build();
 ShareApi.share(content, null);
  Toast.makeText(this, "Succsesfully posted on your wall", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
  .show(); 
}
```